# ¿Cómo aseguro que se guarde var_session en sentencia insert?

Tags: php, mysql, backend

Buen día tengo un problema con la integridad de información en base de datos en mysql, le comento un poco:
Estoy guardando datos de un formulario de 1 textarea a la base de datos con un insert todo los datos se envía bien, la pagina desde donde se envía los datos del textarea es home.php

```
<!-- home.php -->
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>
            Documento
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hola <?php echo $_SESSION['usuario']?>
        <form action="guardar.php">
            <textarea id="comentario" name="comentario"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Guadar">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Como podrán observar en el body se imprime un "Hola **nombre apellido**" que básicamente viene desde un var_session desde login.php

```
<!-- login.php -->
<?php
    session_start();
    $fila=$resultado->fetch_assoc();
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $fila['nombre'] . " " . $fila['apellido'];
?>
```

**PROBLEMA**
Al momento de generar el proceso en guardar.php en el insert se guardan 2 cosas una es el ***comentario*** y otra cosa es ***usuario***, el comentario se recibe por $_POST desde el formulario y el usuario se pasa por $_session

```
<!-- guardar.php -->
<?php
    session_start();
    $comentario = $_POST['comentario'];
    $usuario = $_SESSION['usuario'];
    // Query Insert
    $query = "INSERT INTO tabla.ejemplo(Comentario, Usuario) VALUES ('$comentario', '$usuario')";
    /**
    * Código standard de guardar en base de datos
    */
 ?>
```

Ahora bien se "guardar" las cosas y pongo guardar entre comillas porque a veces los registros en la base de datos solo se guardar el comentario, pero no guarda quién guardo ese comentario

[image: Imagen solo de ejemplo]

Me puede ayudar con este problema. . . ¿Qué hago mal? ¿Cómo lo soluciono? ¿Es el backend o la bd? había leído que las var_session tiene vida útil o algo así

Postdata: Puede que me falten algunas líneas o código, el que estoy poniendo solo es replica miniatura del original, pero es el problema que tengo

Comment: Supongo que desde `login.php` pasas a `home.php` ¿no? No veo el `session_start();` en `login.php`. Luego, tu código tiene el problema de la *programación optimista*, no consideras que pueden ocurrir errores en tu inserción por ejemplo y no controlas absolutamente nada en ese contexto.

Comment: Ya coloque el session_start(); de igual modo te comento que solo es código de ejemplo pero pues explica mi problema básicamente solo lo replique con menos campos, el problema es que "truena" la var_session y empieza a guardar vacíos... ¿Entonces debo manejar algun constraint en caso de un campo vacio?

Comment: *¿Entonces debo manejar algun constraint en caso de un campo vacio?* Pues claro que sí, debes verificar que todos los campos que no deben guardarse vacíos no lo están, y que todos los campos que no deben guardarse `NULL` no lo están, etc. Eso también es parte del fallo que yo llamo *programación optimista*, programar sin verificar esas cosas, asumiendo que siempre tendrán datos, cuando no es así. Aquí, en tu optimismo, piensas que la sesión tendrá siempre datos y resulta que por algún motivo eso no ocurre ... pues debes revisar los datos antes de la inserción.

Comment: Ok muy bien, comprendo tu punto, había pensado en eso de hecho ando en esas correcciones pero creo que xKatooo comprende un poquito más mi problema no se sí puedas revisar su respuesta y brindarme un poco de tu experiencia en base a respuesta de Él

Comment: @Minor podrías añadir que versión de php tienes en la etique por ejemplo ``php-7.4``

Comment: @A.Cedano tiene toda la razón del mundo en cuanto a ese tema....

Comment: PHP 7.3.26 en desarrollo y 7.2 (current) en producción

Answer (score 0):

Es probable que lo que está pasando es que destruyas la sesión y después mientras regresas a páginas anteriores solo renderiza lo que ya había en cache por eso en caso de que tengas una lógica que revise que exista la sesión no funciona, puedes comprobarlo recargando la página, se solucionar esto y hacer que se recargue siempre que regresas, evitando que se cargue con el caché con headers, algo más o menos así

```php
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

Puedes comprobar siempre con un if

```php
if(!$_SESSION['usuario']){
echo "no hay sesión"
die();
//Solo para que no registre nada en la base de datos sql si no hay sesión
}
```

Comment: Me suena que es parte del problema aparte de lo que dice A. Cedano sobre una programación optimista cosa que tiene razón, de momento no eh manejado eso de constraints y procedimientos almancenado. Ahora bien xKatooo podrías decirme donde coloco eso de "header()" en guardar.php me imagino ¿Verdad, puedes explicarme un poco más corrigiendo tu respuesta?

Un detalle más, algunas veces aparte de guardar sin el USUARIO, guarda y duplica registro y uno si guarda con usuario y otro sin usuario.